# Add incrementally ascending numbers in Word find and replace

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, office365, find-and-replace

Is there any way to add ascending numbers in "find and replace" in Word - Office 365 for Mac?

I would like to add a number to every ocurrence of a word.

For example I want to replace:

In Word you can use Word find and replace to replace a Word.

With:

In 1 W you can use 2 W find and replace to replace a 3W.

So every instance of "Word" is replaced by an ascending number and something else..

I found a post to speed it up, but it still takes a lot of time if you do it manually.
[Find and Replace](https://superuser.com/questions/614379/find-and-replace/1714349#1714349)

Comment: Why don't you use a subtitle editor or something like https://www.happyscribe.com? Google `subtitle editor macos`

Comment: Because of the price. if I need 20 hours a month its 240 euros.

Comment: There are freeware solutions https://alternativeto.net/software/subtitle-edit/?platform=mac

Comment: And those can take my transcript and completely automatically they reformat it?

Comment: Nope. But a decent subtitle editor will allow you to select which part of the audio waveform a sentence belongs to, which makes timing much much easier.

Comment: Then I can transcribe all by myself, takes the same time. Can you help me with my question?

Comment: A good solution requires VBA - not easy.

Comment: Search and replace won't do I think, but it might be possible to write a script that inserts a number on a new line, skips 3(?) lines, inserts the next number on a new line et cetera. Do you know any programming languages? VBA would do. I haven't used VBA in the past decade or two.

Comment: The Microsoft-Forum helped out: 

In a Word document, insert a SEQ field and copy it to the clipboard. 

In the Find & Replace dialog box, enter the word you want to search for into the "Find" Field. 

In the "Replace with" field, type: 

^c replacementWord 

(where ^c represents the SEQ field on the clipboard and replacementWord is the word you want instead of the found word). 

Click Replace All.

If the SEQ field isn't updated, you can select all the document content and press F9.

Comment: ^c was the hint I was looking for. So I dont have to copy manually.

Comment: @Officeheini: Put your solution as an answer, it will be more readable than in comment.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft-Forum helped out: In a Word document, insert a SEQ field and copy it to the clipboard. In the Find & Replace dialog box, enter the word you want to search for into the "Find" Field. In the "Replace with" field, type: ^c replacementWord (where ^c represents the SEQ field on the clipboard and replacementWord is the word you want instead of the found word). Click Replace All. If the SEQ field isn't updated, you can select all the document content and press F9.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).